# php json_encode output format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I need to convert the following array from php to this format

```
(php format) [["A","1"],["B","1"],["C","1"],["D","-1"],["E","-1"],["F","-1"]]
```

to this format

```
"A": 1,
        "B": 1,
        "C": 1
```

etc

I'm getting the array using

```
$data[] = array($field1, $field2);
```

and it's being echoed in php using

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

I need to parse this data using javascript for jverctormap

any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: `json_encode()` does what it says on the tin, and jQuery will usually parse it automatically. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php just change

```
$data[] = array($field1, $field2);
```

To

```
$data[$field1] =  $field2;
```

No sense sending it in a format you don't need and having to convert it

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a short snippet to make this transformation on Javascript:

```
var jsonFromArray = {};
arrayToBeTransformed.forEach(function(v){
    jsonFromArray[v[0]] = v[1];
});
console.log(jsonFromArray);
```

Where arrayToBeTransformed has this value:

[["A","1"],["B","1"],["C","1"],["D","-1"],["E","-1"],["F","-1"]]

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to send the array in its natural format, then process it client-side.

**Javascript**

```
var data = [["A","1"],["B","1"],["C","1"],["D","-1"],["E","-1"],["F","-1"]];

var output = {};

data.forEach(function(a) {
    output[a[0]] = Number(a[1]);
});

/*
output will be 
{
    "A": 1,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 1,
    "D": -1,
    "E": -1,
    "F": -1
}
*/
```